# Git workflow for demoing features before release

Tags: git, gitflow

My team and I are looking for a git workflow for demoing experimental changes/features in our web application before they are released. Our audience includes our project manager and designer -- people who we do not expect to run an instance of our app -- so we need to host the webserver as well.

In our first attempt, we created a `demo` branch and merged in our feature branches as changes were ready to be shared. After a change was approved, the feature branch was to be merged into `master` and released. Unfortunately, we found that keeping `demo` up to date with `master` consistently resulted in merge conflicts.

We could do something like each feature branch gets its own instance of our application, but the ideal would be grouping all demo features together and serving them in one place.

Does anyone have any advice?

EDIT: For clarification, the merge conflicts seem to be the result of files being changed on both `master` and `demo`. Our feature branches tend to be long-lived (say, around a week while things are tweaked), and inevitably bug fixes/other changes are made to `master` in the mean time.

Comment: Do not use feature branches. Use feature toggles. And make sure you demo on environment that is as close to production as possible.

Answer (score 3):

If you use gitflow the develop branch can be used in the same way as your demo branch with no merge conflicts.

However. Your main problem isnt getting pre release version of the code. This could be done in any number of ways.

Your main problem is how to handle the situation if one feature in the demo is not approved for release.

You can't change the code, commenting out the problem feature, and release without retesting and redemoing etc.

The only workable solution is to demo each fearure separately in its feature branch and only merge to master/develop once approved.

This is equivilant to trunk based development, you have to keep the features small because you have a constant stream of changes needing to be merged back up into other features

Feature toggles are highly spoken of, but deeply flawed. If you want to test you have to test each combination of feature toggles and it soon becomes impossible. Avoid at all costs.

Comment: You don't have to test each combination of feature toggles. You mostly need to test the combination(s) that you intended to use when the code under test is released. Generally this is just one or two combinations.

Comment: @bdsl true, if you never toggle a feature, but this would be the same as commenting out code. There would be no purpose to the toggle.

Comment: Feature toggles look a little loose (ie, easy to forget about and accidentally release the wrong version).

Comment: @danwoz: only when used in an non-systematic way, or when applied wrong.

Comment: @Ewan: the same argument you gave against feature toggles could be applied to any (regular) configuration option in an application. And just because an application allows lot of configuration options, it does not become "untestable".

Comment: @docbrown normally configuration settings apply to a single thing. database connection, loglevel, rate limit etc. They have one setting and If they are wrong the whole app stops working. Feature toggles by definition affect each other. does the discount code feature work? does the discount code feature work during a sale? does the discount code feature work with the new basket? does it work with the new basket and a sale etc.

Comment: @danwos 100% should feature X be on or off when deploying microservice Y to market Z? who knows anymore

Comment: @Ewan: you seem to have a very restricted viewpoint on what regular configuration option are, and how feature toggles are used. I would normally give this answer a -1 since it demonizes something which could actually be a solution for the OP's problem (but the initial part seems to be good enough to compensate). Not saying feature toggles are always a good solution, but they are definitely not as bad as this answer characterizes them.

Comment: well im generalising, obvs the more feature toggly your config is, or the more options your app has in general the more combination tests you have to do. I do think this is a specific issue to feature toggling over other optional setting though. people seem to think they can skip these tests for feature toggles

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear from your description, are your conflicts caused by genuinely different changes in different feature branches which happened to be in same place, or changes in same feature branch which somehow lost their history information. If the latter, you probably are trying to avoid force pushing the `demo`. So that all the temporary merges are there in history and they cause conflicts.

Better approach would be re-creating the `demo` each time from latest master and merge there the feature branches you want to demonstrate. Such approach works for the git project itself, they have [pu](https://github.com/git/git/commits/pu) branch which merges all proposed patches and is updated as often as any patch has any update. This way you would avoid unnecessary merge conflicts because of different versions of same change clashed together.

The merge conflicts which happen when different feature branches edit same place are probably unavoidable completely. If the feature branches live long enough so that you have to merge them several times again and again, resolving same conflicts, you may want to try [git rerere](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere) - it really helps in such cases.

Comment: Good point. I've updated the description with more info about our conflicts. `git rerere` sounds really interesting, and may be the solution to our problem.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having demo updated with master each time a feature is merged, I think you can create different demo branches from master each time a demo is required. (demo/feature_A, demo/featureB, etc)

Comment: This may well be what we end up going with, but that does mean we'd have to have a separate instance of our webserver running for each feature, probably. Not the end of the world, but it would be nice to put them all together.